# Open an XPinC from a desktop icon

Tags: xpages, xpinc

How do create an icon on the Windows desktop that will launch Notes and open an XPinC page automatically? Is it as simple as adding something to launch the XPage to the the icon or do I need to set something in the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest shortcut is to use Notes URL format.

`notes://server/path/application.nsf/xpage.xsp?OpenXpage` should work.

Comment: Thank you - I knew it had to be simple. I also set the Launch option to open the XPages so that made it even easier. Just have to open the NSF since it is an XPinC application